# Installing drivers for 3.5" HDMI Touch Screen OSOYOO

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, display, touchscreen

I am trying to install the drivers for HDMI Touch Screen 1920x1080 Display 3.5 Inches LCD Monitor for Raspberry Pi (https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B01N5G02MZ/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1). The amazon product description provides a fairly simple explanation on how to install the driver (http://kookye.com/2017/01/18/install-3-5-hdmi-touch-screen-linux-driver-on-raspberry-pi/) I followed those step by step, but the LCD Display keeps white... Also, now I am not able to access my raspberry pi via my second PC display, as after installing the drivers it does not seem to recognize it anymore. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Operationg System: Raspbian

LCD Display: KeDei Raspberry Pi Display 3.5 inch HDMILCD 18bit version 1.1 2017/2/1

Answer (score 0):

There are different images being provided.  I have a similar screen and had to try another image until it worked. Unzipping and burning image to SD Card using Win32DiskImager. Did you try any of the other images [provided here as part of the referenced tutorial](http://kookye.com/2016/12/15/raspberry-pi-3-5-hdmi-touch-screen-installation-guide/)?

Comment: I tried it with the raspbian image with another sd card and it did not work either. Further on, I really wouldnt want to flash my current system.